# STM32 GPIO register level input

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, gpio, keil

It's actually a basic code for controlling buzzer with leds. I did with HAL libraries.But the institution I was working with wanted to do this at the register level too. But I couldn't it. It's not too complicated however i don't understand where the problem is.
My code in below.

```
    #include "stm32f10x.h"
void SystemCoreClockConfigure(void) 
{
    RCC->CR |= ((uint32_t)RCC_CR_HSION);                     // Enable HSI
  while ((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSIRDY) == 0);                  // Wait for HSI Ready

  RCC->CFGR = RCC_CFGR_SW_HSI;                             // HSI is system clock
  while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_HSI);  // Wait for HSI used as system clock

  FLASH->ACR  = FLASH_ACR_PRFTBE;                          // Enable Prefetch Buffer
  FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY;                         // Flash 1 wait state

  RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV1;                         // HCLK = SYSCLK
  RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV2;                        // APB1 = HCLK/2
  RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV1;                        // APB2 = HCLK

  RCC->CR &= ~RCC_CR_PLLON;                                // Disable PLL

 // PLL configuration:  = HSI/2 * 12 = 48 MHz
  RCC->CFGR &= ~(RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC | RCC_CFGR_PLLXTPRE | RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL);
  RCC->CFGR |=  (RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC_HSI_Div2 | RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL12);

  RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;                                 // Enable PLL
  while((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY) == 0) __NOP();           // Wait till PLL is ready

  RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_SW;                               // Select PLL as system clock source
  RCC->CFGR |=  RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
  while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL);  // Wait till PLL is system clock src
}
```

This is the first oscillator activation part.I know that there is no problem until the main function.
In main:

```
    int main(void)
    {

        SystemCoreClockUpdate();
        SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000);     
        RCC->APB2ENR |= (1UL << 2);                /* Enable GPIOA clock            */
        RCC->APB2ENR |= (1UL << 4);                /* Enable GPIOC clock            */  

    //  Configure the GPIO Buttons 
    GPIOA->CRL   = 0x00000044;  //1SET    // GPIOA -> 0,1    
    GPIOC->CRL   = 0x00004400;  //3SET    // GPIOC -> 3,2   

    while (1)
  { 
    if(GPIOA->IDR == 0x0000003) // PA1 ON (Led4) //
    {
        GPIOC->CRH   = 0x00000002;  //  BUZZER SET 
        GPIOC->BSRR  = 0x00000100;  //  BUZZER ON
    }
  } 
 }
```

I'm using keil and I know that if i only set and on buzzer after 
GPIOC->CRL   = 0x00004400;  //3SET    // GPIOC -> 3,2 
 it's working.But with the reading input to button with GPIO->IDR(Input Data Reg.) It's not toggle or whatever i don't know.I've been stuck here for a week and it's really annoying. Heelp me !?

Comment: [Reference Manual for STM32f103](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjkr7TrJzZAhWFGCwKHRkIAI4QFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Freference_manual%2Fcd00171190.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2f4OetUc11dkGY0vec5If9)
You can see the GPIO registers in manual

Comment: seems that this is not good idea: `GPIOA->IDR == 0x0000003` this if will be true only if both inputs will be high and no other signals, but are you sure that other signals will be low? better will be to mask these tow bits: `GPIOA->IDR & 0x0000003 == 0x00000003`

Comment: It's work man thank you !

Comment: @vlk, add you message as an answer instead, so that the question can be marked as resolved

Comment: Do not use "magic" numbers. Use human friendly definitions.

Comment: We see lots of hints to improve the situation. Sadly, collecting them to an answer is not accepted (for not being complete enough?), I've tried it. => I'll propose to close/remove this question again since missing information is not added and original poster may have abandoned the topic during the 2 years of this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code inside your while loop is completely wrong!

```
while(1)
{
   if((GPIOA->IDR & 0x02) == 0x02) // 0x02 = 0b10 = PA1 (LED4)
   {
      GPIOC->BSRR = 0x100; // ON
   }
   else
   {
      GPIOC->BSRR = (0x100 << 16); // OFF
   }
}
```

and also set the GPIOC->CRH register only once before the while loop.